# Question for the derivation of the probability of a trajectory

Tags: reinforcement-learning, probability

I'm studying reinforcement learning now and I'm quite a newbie to this field.
I have some questions about how to derive the equation as below.

$p_{\theta}(s_{1},a_{1},\dots,s_T,a_T)=p(s_1)\prod_{t=1}^T(\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t))$

The equation above is the probability of a trajectory.

But in my opinion, the equation should be,
$p_{\theta}(s_{1},a_{1},\dots,s_T,a_T)=p(s_1)\prod_{t=1}^T\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)\prod_{t=1}^{T-1}p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)$

I don't know why $p(s_{T+1}|s_T,a_T)$ emerges in the original equation because there is no $s_{T+1},a_{T+1}$ in the trajectory. I think I'm missing something.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: This might be just bayesian factorization. Do you have the image of the trajectory graph?

Comment: @desert_ranger Oh I don't have it. But it's just the general trajectory which starts at s_1 and then do the action a_1, so on and forth. I know it's a bayesian factorization, but I still don't know why s_T+1 comes in the first equation.